# how can i add action to plus button (button on navbar) in tabbar VC?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

i want to add action to plus button (button on navigation bar) in tab bar VC how can do it?

Comment: Why would you add a button to Tab bar's Navigation bar? Why dont you add a button to Tab bar's View controller, and if the function of these button is same write a simple protocol and provide default extension to it and make your view controllers confirm to it

Comment: Maybe you just put the question not in the correct way... by `+` button you want to be able to add things? What kind of action do you want to attach to that `NavigationBarButtonItem`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the programmatically right bar item button into navigation then you can add button action.